# Detect click inside/outside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```css
.container
{
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
  background-color:grey;
  }
.box
{
  width:150px;
  height:30px;
  background-color:white;
  position:relative;
  top:130px;
  left:10px;
  color:black;
  }
.window
{
  height:300px;
  width:250px;
  background-color:red;
  position:absolute;
  left:200px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box" contenteditable="true">
  </div>
  <div class="window">
  </div>
</div>
```

Hello,

I have one question, is possible to detect focus and blur into div (`class="box"`). I would like to click in div `class="box"` (when div is active) and the red box (`class="window"`) fadeOut and then when click outside "box" "window" fadeIn ?

Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that using jQuery `focus` and `blur` event handler, `.box` on `focus` it hides `.window` and on `blur` it shows `.window`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.box').on('focus',function(){
   $('.window').hide(200);
  });
  $('.box').on('blur',function(){
   $('.window').show(200);
  });
});
```

```css
.container
{
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
  background-color:grey;
  }
.box
{
  width:150px;
  height:30px;
  background-color:white;
  position:relative;
  top:130px;
  left:10px;
  color:black;
  }
.window
{
  height:300px;
  width:250px;
  background-color:red;
  position:absolute;
  left:200px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box" contenteditable="true">
  </div>
  <div class="window">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome @PiotrS :-), well this can be even achieve using CSS and Javascript. As given by other developers.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done w/o using script, here in combination with the `:focus` pseudo class and the immediate sibling selector `+`

*Note, for an element other than form elements to get focus, it need the `tab-index` set.*

Stack snippet

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: grey;
}
.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  top: 130px;
  left: 10px;
  color: black;
}
.window {
  height: 300px;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

.box:focus + .window {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div tab-index="1" class="box" contenteditable="true">
  </div>
  <div class="window">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @PiotrS May I ask why you use script when it can be done with CSS? ... That is the wrong way to go

Comment: I have started my adventure with javascript css few month ago, and I thought that use script is better

Comment: @PiotrS Nope, it is not, you don't replace CSS stuff with script .. or the other way around. Script will slow down your page if you start using it for everything

Answer (score 0):

You can detect focus/blur events on the `.box` and in those event handlers you can take the appropriate actions.

```js
var boxEl = document.querySelector('.box');

boxEl.addEventListener('focus', function(e) {
  console.log('focused');
});

boxEl.addEventListener('blur', function(e) {
  console.log('blurred');
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: grey;
}
.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  top: 130px;
  left: 10px;
  color: black;
}
.window {
  height: 300px;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box" contenteditable="true">
  </div>
  <div class="window">
  </div>
</div>
```